# behat fillField xpath giving error?

Tags: behat

This line of code:

```
$this->fillField('xpath','//fieldset[@id="address-container"]/input[@name="address_add[0][city]"]', "Toronto");
```

Is giving me this error

```
Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "xpath" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)
```

The reason I want to use xpath in my fillField is because there are actually multiple `input[@name="address_add[0][city]"]` in my html document.  I figure an xpath will let me target specifically the field I want to populate.

What's the best way to fill out just the `input[@name="address_add[0][city]"]` that is a descendant of `fieldset[@id="address-container"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the method in the wright way.

As i see here `xpath` is taken as selector.
The method expects 2 parameters:
`identifier` - value of one of attributes 'id|name|label|value'
`value` - the string you need to set as value

If you want to use css|xpath then you need  to use `find` method first.

For example:

```
$this->find('xpath', 'your_selector')->setValue('your_string');
```

> Please note that find might return `null` and using `setValue` will result in a fatal exception.

You should have something like this:

```
$field = find('xpath', 'your_selector');

if ($field === null) {
    // throw exception
}

$field->setValue('your_string');
```

Also your selector could be written as:

```
#address-container input[name*=city] - this with css
```

or

```
//fieldset[@id="address-container"]//input[contains(@name, 'city')]  - this with xpath
```

> Make sure you take advantage of your IDE editor when you have any doubts using a method and you should find a php doc with what parameters are expected and what the method will return.
>
> If you are using css/xpath a lot you could override `find` method to detect automatically the type of selector and to use it like `$this->find($selector);`
>
> Also you could define another method to wait for the element and to handle the exception in one place, for example `waitForElement($selector)` that could contain a conditional wait up to 10 seconds and that throws exception if not found.